# Create a product type like Configurable Product in Magento Programatically

Tags: php, magento

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2

I'm planning to provide an option "Sell it your Self" in my magento store, User can sell the products if they are having the same type of product.

For that i want to create a base product like Configurable Product but with out Global attribute & instead of global attribute dropdown i want get my custom block.

How can i create this ?

Any Ideas ?

Comment: What did you get so far?

Comment: @GerarddeVisser i'm just planning i didn't touch it because i don't know from where i have to start this....